# Remove element in unordered_set using iterator in a loop

Tags: c++, unordered-set

Please consider the following code:

`Class MyClass` is a self-defined class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int v) : Val(v) {}
    int Val;
};
```

Then the following code will cause `Debug Assertion Failed` in the loop just after calling `it = T.erase(it);`:

```
unordered_set<MyClass*> T;
unordered_set<MyClass*>::iterator it;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    T.insert(new MyClass(i));

for (it = T.begin(); it != T.end(); it++)
{
    if ( (*it)->Val == 5 )
        it = T.erase(it); // After this line executes, in the next loop, the error occurs.
}
```

How to solve it and Why? 
PS： My environment: VS2010

Comment: if you erase the last element, you set `it = T.end();`, then execute `it++`, which is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that the last element has Val = 5.

`it = T.erase(it)` is called, and `it` is set to `T.end()`.

Then `it++` is called, which causes an error because `it` is already set to end.

Essentially... when you erase an element in your current code, you end up double-advancing the iterator.

You could go with something like this instead....

```
for (it = T.begin(); it != T.end(); (*it)->Val == 5? it = T.erase(it) : ++it)
  ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I usually do:

```
for (auto it = T.begin(); it != T.end(); )
{
    if ((*it)->value == 5) it = T.erase(it);
    else ++it;
}
```

This might increase readability if your erase condition gets more complex.