# Is this a safe way to implement intersect and sub for sets

Tags: c++, stl, set, unordered-set

```
void get_intersection_and_sub(std::unordered_set<int64_t>& intersection,
                              std::unordered_set<int64_t>& query_set,
                              const std::unordered_set<int64_t>& other_set) {
    intersection.clear();
    for(auto item : query_set) {
        if (other_set.count(item) > 0) {
            intersection.insert(item);
            query_set.erase(item);
        }
    }
}
std::unorder_set<int64_t> inter;
std::unorder_set<int64_t> query({12342});
std::unorder_set<int64_t> target_set({12342, 157059258443, 7, 15705443, 140496216873, 175793035233});
get_intersection_and_sub(inter, query_set, target_set);
```

In my case, I call the codes above, the right value of `inter` is `{12342}`, but unexpectedly sometimes I get `inter` as `{12342, 7}`. Is there anything wrong I use about `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: You cannot `erase` from `query_set` while iterating over-it I think. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252386/remove-element-in-unordered-set-using-iterator-in-a-loop

Comment: Off-topic but is there any reason why you pass `intersection` and clear it instead of simply creating it in the function and returning it?

Comment: @Roy Huang Why is the name query declared twice?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow updated :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `.erase` while iterating a container like this in C++, what you have is undefined behavior, hence the kind of random output you get some times. You could do:

```cpp
intersection.clear();
for (auto it = std::begin(query_set); it != std::end(query_set); ) {
    if (other_set.count(*it) > 0) {
        intersection.insert(*it);
        it = query_set.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested with `std::set` to replace `std::unordered_set` in my codes just now, the mistake didn't appear.

Comment: @RoyHuang That's undefined behavior, so anything can happen. When you erase the element, the iterator becomes invalid, so incrementing it becomes UB. That's the same with old loop and manual iterators or new `for (auto x : C)` loop, the iterator is just hidden in the latter.

Comment: Is it a good practice if I loop the const set `for (auto item : other_set)` and do the `intersection.insert(item)` `query_set.erase(item)`?

Comment: @RoyHuang That's another option yes. If you do this, you're going to lookup the item a lots, so you may want to check `query_set.find(item)` and use the returned iterator to erase instead of doing `query_set.count()` and then `query_set.erase()`, although if you have small sets it won't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the interface of the function is not good. Apart from pushing common elements the function also clears the unordered set passed as the first parameter.

When you are using the range based for loop then you may not remove elements from the container because the deleted element makes the current iterator invalid. You should use the ordinary for loop. The range based for loop uses iterators under the hood.

The function can be defined the following way

```
template <typename T>
std::unordered_set<T> remove_common( std::unordered_set<T> &set1,
    const std::unordered_set <T> &set2 )
{
    std::unordered_set<T> result;

    for (auto it = std::begin( set1 ); it != std::end( set1 ); )
    {
        if (set2.count( *it ))
        {
            result.insert( *it );
            it = set1.erase( it );
        }
        else
        {
            std::advance( it, 1 );
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
std::unordered_set<T> remove_common( std::unordered_set<T> &set1,
    const std::unordered_set <T> &set2 )
{
    std::unordered_set<T> result;

    for (auto it = std::begin( set1 ); it != std::end( set1 ); )
    {
        if (set2.count( *it ))
        {
            result.insert( *it );
            it = set1.erase( it );
        }
        else
        {
            std::advance( it, 1 );
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int64_t> set1( { 12342 } );
    std::unordered_set<int64_t> set2( { 12342, 157059258443, 7, 15705443, 140496216873, 175793035233 } );

    auto result = remove_common( set1, set2 );

    std::cout << "result: ";
    for (const auto &item : result) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "set1: ";
    for (const auto &item : set1) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
result: 12342
set1:
```

Comment: Is it a good practice if I loop the const set `for (auto item : other_set)` and do the `intersection.insert(item)` `query_set.erase(item)`?

Comment: @RoyHuang I have not understood what you mean.:)

Comment: @RoyHuang You could use and this loop also because in this case the container other_set is not being changed.